# MySQL Order by subquery column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I have problem with sql query. The idea is to select all loans that are after payment (status 1/2/3) between 8 and 21 days with calculated value from payment_day til now.

I have already done some query but can't use columns days_after_payment and days_after_part_payment in WHERE section. I would like to have one column like days_after_payment based on loan type.

```
SELECT l.*,
(SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `loan_part` WHERE `loan_id` = l.id AND `paid`=0) AS left_to_pay, 
-(DATEDIFF((SELECT date FROM `loan_part` WHERE `loan_id` = l.id AND `paid`=0 AND `date`<CURDATE() ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1), NOW())) AS days_after_part_payment,
-(DATEDIFF(l.payment_date, NOW())) AS days_after_payment
FROM loan l
WHERE (l.type=1 or l.type=2) AND (l.status=1 OR l.status=2 OR l.status=3)
GROUP BY l.client_id
ORDER BY 
CASE l.type 
    WHEN 1 THEN days_after_payment
    WHEN 2 THEN days_after_part_payment
    ELSE 1 END 
ASC

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_date` date DEFAULT NULL  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2068 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loan_part` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `loan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1751 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Update1 : I had to cut unnecessary columns and rewrite it into English from my native language.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY 7
```

"7" means the 7th field in the SELECT.  That works for `GROUP BY` also.  I had to see the table definition to count how many in `l.*`.

How come `id` is not declared `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: May be I've done something wrong while export structure. Ids are autoincrement for sure.